# EF support with SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I am working on a asp.net project where my client is using SQL Server 2005. I want to design the data layer using Entity Framework 6, so, I just want to inquire if SQL Server 2005 is supported by Entity Framework 6. If not, which versions of Entity Framework are supported by this version of SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, EF 6 supports SQL Server 2005 and later, SQL Server 2000 is NOT supported.